# Golden test within smallcheck property test

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

I have a manually-written "golden test" (write actual output to file, compare to "golden" expected file for equality) within a smallcheck `property` which enumerates over all of the constructors for a given enum.

I would like to convert this to tasty-golden. There exists a package, tasty-smallcheck, which allows you to run smallcheck tests in a tasty test suite. However, what I actually need is the inverse: to run a golden test inside of a smallcheck test.

Is there an obvious solution here that I'm missing? Or do I just have to rewrite a version of `Test.SmallCheck.forAll` in tasty lingo that enumerates over all possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

My dissatisfying workaround for this was to use `listSeries 1 :: [MyEnum]` manually rather than using an actual smallcheck `forAll` test.